# Ubuntu 19.10 - Backup doesn't work after upgrade

Tags: backup, 19.10, deja-dup

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04 and the backup has stopped working.

It now shows, `Backup Failed`, `Could not log into Google servers. OK`
There was no such problem before the upgrade.

I tried removing my google account and re-adding it from *Settings* -> *Online Accounts*. But it didn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Same problem with me, did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here...

Installing the snap instead seems to work: `snap install deja-dup --classic`